# React Native Update Release APK

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I have create a release apk. Now I have changed the codes. I modified version number. When I generate release apk, it is not updated. it is same as old version. How can I do?

Comment: where are you changing the version number?

Comment: build.gradle file. It is changed. The problem is not that. Because I can publish the new app to Google Play. But the new app is same as old app features.

Comment: it takes some time to update... if you see that your release is going from build 22 to build 23, then google is accepting the new build. this is a better question fr google if thats not the case for you.

Comment: Modify the version code (android:versionCode, not android:versionName) in build.gradle

Comment: I modified version code and version name. The problem is not that. the problem is creating new release apk.

Comment: Contact Play Console support, they would be able to provide a customized answer for your problem. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-develope

Comment: How to create release apk for updated version in react native? Can you explain it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the solution provided below:

1. Modify the code (it must be different);
2. Make sure to update the app version code as other have pointed;
3. Next step is to [generate a signed APK](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html).
4. If successful, [run this command](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#generating-the-release-apk) so the CLI will bundle your code to production, generating the APK.
5. At the end, the new Signed APK might be at "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/" folder which is inside your project folder.

Comment: I have a question for 3. step. Should I do this step every time for updating? Or I should do 4. step only?

Comment: Yes, every new production build must be naturally re-signed as well as rebuilt. However, once you've setup properly the 3rd step, it's just a matter of running the command.

Comment: I already did it but this was not a solution. I have found a solution. That is

Comment: Please update your post with the solution so other people can get around it :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution.

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```